# Searching jsonb column by array of value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

In my Ruby on Rails project I have `SurveyResult` model with the following scope:

```
class SurveyResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_purpose, -> (purpose) {
    where("raw #>> '{survey, purpose}' = ?", purpose)
  }
end
```

`raw` is a jsonb column. Data in this column is represented by following schema:

```
survey: { purpose: 'data' }
```

This scope works fine if I try to get survey results which purpose is `data`:

```
SurveyResult.with_purpose('data')
```

but when I also want to find some survey results with other purpose:

```
SurveyResult.with_purpose(['data', 'risk'])
```

it returns following error:

```
2.3.1 :042 > SurveyResult.with_purpose(['risk', 'data'])
  SurveyResult Load [dev] (1.5ms)  SELECT "survey_results".* FROM "survey_results" WHERE (raw #>> '{survey, purpose}' = 'risk','data')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: ...CT "survey_results".* FROM "survey_results" WHERE (raw #>> '...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "survey_results".* FROM "survey_results" WHERE (raw #>> '{survey, purpose}' = 'risk','data')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.where("id = ?", 1)
Corresponding query to the database would look like,
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (id = 1)

User.where("id IN (?)", [1,2,3])
Corresponding query to the database would look like,
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (id IN (1,2,3))

"= ?" this operator expects on a single argument, so if you are passing an array to it an error would be thrown 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record

In order to pass an array you should modify your query to:

"IN (?)", This operator would work if you wanted to pass a single value to it or an array.

Both would work fine
User.where("id IN (?)", 1)
User.where("id IN (?)", [1,2,3])
```